# How to detect removed card with MFRC522

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, rfid

I am working on project where I need to read ID of NFC tag, and then perform some action based on that ID. So far I am able to read it once (object with tag is on the reader whole time), but I also need to have some feedback when object  is taken off. I am using MFRC522 reader with RPi and [SimpleMFRC522](https://github.com/pimylifeup/MFRC522-python/blob/master/SimpleMFRC522.py)  library.

I've tried poking around code in that, but without any success. Do you have any directions / ideas? I have following code:

```
reader = SimpleMFRC522.SimpleMFRC522()
buffor = 0

while continue_reading:
    try:
        id, text = reader.read()
        if(buffor != id):
            print id
            udp_send(id) 
    buffor = id
    finally:
            time.sleep(0.5)
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on the code at the link you provided, it looks like the `reader.read` method blocks while there is no ID to read. Instead, it just continues to try to read until it sees an ID.

However, there is another method called `reader.read_no_block` which seems to return `None` if there is no ID to read, so you could use that instead.

```
reader = SimpleMFRC522.SimpleMFRC522()
last_id = None

def exit_event():
    print('tag has left the building')

while continue_reading:
    id, text = reader.read_no_block()
    if id and id != last_id:
        # process new tag here
        last_id = id
        continue
    elif not id and last_id:
        # if there's no id to read, and last_id is not None,
        # then a tag has left the reader
        exit_event()
        last_id = None
```

You will probably want to do some debouncing so that `exit_event` doesn't get called in error when the reader mistakenly misses a read on a tag.